# cant figure out how to read from utf-16 file and syslog it out to utf-8

Tags: python, decoding

I am trying to take a file that is in UTF-16 format and then `syslog` it out to a `syslog` server in UTF-8 format.  i am pretty new to python and programming. 
Everything is working except that it's not sending it out as UTF-8 in the `syslog`.

**Code**

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import tailer
import os
import codecs

logger = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#add handler to the logger
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('x.x.x.x', 514))

#add formatter to the handler
formatter = logging.Formatter('')

handler.formatter = formatter
logger.addHandler(handler)

while True:
    for line in tailer.follow(open('z:\\ERRORLOG')):
        logger.info(str.decode('utf-8'), line)
```

> i also tried the below at the end

```
while True:
for line in tailer.follow(open('z:\\ERRORLOG')):
    logger.info(str(line, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Please format the code so it is readable.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: sorry Scott.  just figured out how to add it properly afterwards

Comment: Python 3.  and this is reading from MS SQL error log

Comment: Probably you should use encoding parameter in open function instead of string's decode method https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use additional parameter `encoding` when you open file.
simple example:

```
with open('utf-16.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16') as fr:
    with open('utf-8.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw:
        for line in fr:
            fw.write(line)
```

in your case:

```
while True:
    with open('z:\\ERRORLOG', encoding='utf-16') as fr:
        for line in tailer.follow(fr):
            logger.info(line)
```

Comment: Hi nobby.  thanks for the reply.  But i dont want to write a second file.  i want to syslog it directly off in a different encoding.  if i create a new file with the new encoding then it could lead to other problems.  is there a way i can use the encoding option in the logger.info section?

Comment: @Rlourenco, I've updated the answer. The main point is python would decode file by itself if you pass proper encoding name in function `open`.

Comment: thanks Nobby.  your answer did put me on the right path.  i however didnt get it to output in the right format but i found another solution to my problem so thank you.